# Rails : speed up styling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap

Maybe you know [bootstrap css from twitter](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) ?
It's absolutely amazing  !
It give you the ability to quick start a project using some default css classes.

I think it's a great idea, especially for rails project. Because rails allow the programmer to quickly develops an application and bootstrap allow the programmer to quickly style it !

But somes plugins needs some configuration to integrate great with bootstrap and sometimes it's a pain...
So is there a repository where somes major plugins like simple_form or will_paginate are forked to integrate well with bootstrap ?

And in a more general way, is there a repository where your can have a rails application with some great styles ?
With tools like Sass or Less it will be great to have some default mixins to speed up the styling task !

Answer (score 1):

simple form already works well if you edit your inititializer and bundle the edge version from github.

```
gem 'simple_form', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.git'
```

Here is a demo app by a guy that did all the hard work:

https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap

then you get bootstrap style forms like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @article, :wrapper => :inline do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :disabled_text, :hint => "a simple input", :label => 'My Input' %>
  <%= f.input :disabled_text, :disabled => true, :hint => "an example of disabled input" %>
  <%= f.input :content_type, :collection => content_type_options, :hint => "simple select box" %>
<% end -%>
```